# My Python code pass simple tests but not extended ones due to performance constrains

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, string, algorithm, performance

I'm teaching myself to code with Python and I've been completing kata's (mainly 7 kyu for now) on Codewars for a while. While trying to level up stumbled on [following 6 kyu kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55b080eabb080cd6f8000035/python), that looked to be achievable with my knowledge:

> Complete the function that takes a string as an input, and return a list of all the unpaired characters (i.e. they show up an odd number of times in the string), in the order they were encountered as an array.
>
> In case of multiple appearances to choose from, take the last occurence of the unpaired character.
>
> Notes:
>
> A wide range of characters is used, and some of them may not render properly in your browser.
>   Your solution should be linear in terms of string length to pass the last test.
>   Examples:
>
> "Hello World"   -->  ["H", "e", " ", "W", "r", "l", "d"]
>
> "Codewars"      -->  ["C", "o", "d", "e", "w", "a", "r", "s"]
>
> "woowee"        -->  []
>
> "wwoooowweeee"  -->  []
>
> "racecar"       -->  ["e"]
>
> "Mamma"         -->  ["M"]
>
> "Mama"          -->  ["M", "m"]

The following Python 3.6.0 code pass sample tests:

```py
def function_name(s):
    result = []
    lengthS = len(s)
    dictResult = {}

    for item in s[-1:(-1 * lengthS - 1):-1]:
        numLetters = 0
        for number in range(lengthS):
            if item == s[number]:
                numLetters = numLetters + 1
        if numLetters % 2 != 0:
            dictResult[item] = numLetters

    for key in list(dictResult.keys())[-1:(-1 * (len(list(dictResult))) - 1):-1]:
        result.append(key)

    return result
```

Running a full round of tests fails due to :

> Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)

Commenting some parts of code allows me to fail full round of tests quicker so I could see tests use very long strings.

It is clear that my code is not performance optimised. Read some articles on algorithms and I suspect my code lacks in performance due to *for* loop within another *for* loop, which is O(n²) complexity operation. And this is where I've stuck for a while. I'm not sure if this is the only piece of code that needs to be changed and if it is - just cannot get around understanding how this could be done.

**Note**. Please do not post answers with complete solution to this problem. I'd rather wish to figure the final code myself. So I would be glad if you could point to sections of my code that requires attention with suggestions, example code or further reading.

Comment: Hi Alex, IMO opinion your question is well suited for Code Review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ you should give it a try.

Comment: @Alex Can you share the link?

Comment: @RomainL. I think it's on topic because OP doesn't have a working solution yet. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102852/stack-overflow-vs-code-review-vs-software-engineering-vs-codegolf

Comment: @vivek_23 True, but this code (and OP) could benefit from a code review anyway.

Comment: @vivek_23 Which link are you looking for? For this particular kata on Codewars?

Comment: @Alex Yes, the kata link.

Comment: @Heike Yes, I was just defending it's valid for SO too.

Comment: @vivek_23 updated question to include URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your note:

> Note. Please do not post answers with complete solution to this
>   problem. I'd rather wish to figure the final code myself. So I would
>   be glad if you could point to sections of my code that requires
>   attention with suggestions, example code or further reading.

- I will be posting only the bottlenecks, rest is up to you to figure out.
  Your code has

  ```
  for number in range(lengthS):
          if item == s[number]:
              numLetters = numLetters + 1
  ```

which basically means you are going through the entire string and checking where all `item` character exists and collect the count. This is making your code quadratic in nature(O(n^2)) because for each character, there is an entire scan in the string taking n^2 steps asymptotically.

To overcome this, you can collect the count while iterating the string itself by taking the help of the dictionary methods. So, your code can change from

```
for item in s[-1:(-1 * lengthS - 1):-1]:
        numLetters = 0
        for number in range(lengthS):
            if item == s[number]:
                numLetters = numLetters + 1
        if numLetters % 2 != 0:
            dictResult[item] = numLetters
```

to

```
for item in s[-1:(-1 * lengthS - 1):-1]:
        dictResult[item] = dictResult.get(item,0) + 1
```

This would collect all counts for a particular character in a single pass, making it O(n) in nature.

- Second observation I found is that there is no point(or any advantage) in traversing the string in a reverse way, like below:

  ```
  for item in s[-1:(-1 * lengthS - 1):-1]:
  ```

  You can instead try simply looping over them one by one, like below:

  ```
  for item in s:
      dictResult[item] = dictResult.get(item,0) + 1
  ```
- Third is to observe whether you really need any `item` in `dictResult` if it's count is even. If any character's count comes out to be even at any point in iteration, you can simply remove it from `dictResult`. This way you would only have odd valued keys in `dictResult`. This also makes your code a bit space efficient(sometimes significant).
  Note that the odd valued keys in `dictResult` will not be ordered in terms of the order of characters in which the output is expected. I leave this as an exercise for you to figure out.

**Update:**

It seems that from Python3.7, the keys in dictionary are stored in the order in which they are inserted. So, it's relatively easy to match the order of output.

**Correct Snippet:**

```
def odd_one_out(s):
    result = []
    dictResult = {}

    for item in s:
        dictResult[item] = dictResult.get(item,0) + 1
        if dictResult[item] % 2 == 0:
            dictResult.pop(item)
    return list(dictResult.keys())
```

Comment: Thanks! Swaping two "for" loops with dictionary method and making few other tweaks resulted in pass for extended tests within ~3000 ms. I had similar logic, but couldn't get my head around figuring out this simple code. Regarding your 2nd observation.Task requires "In case of multiple appearances to choose from, take the last occurence of the unpaired character" which, in case of "Hello World", would keep first occurence of letter "l" within dictionary, not the last one. So iterating string from the last character makes more sense to me.

Comment: @Alex Glad to help. If you followed by third observation, you will always have the last occurrence of `l` only set in your dictionary. You can see my accepted solution in this post's update.

Comment: The keys of the dictionary are stored in order only from python3.7! In python3.6 there was an implementation detail in CPython that leaded to the same behavior but it wasn't true for other interpreters like pypy (often used by the kind of platforms OP mentioned)

Comment: @MarcoZamboni Thanks for the update :) Not a python guy, so didn't knew that. Thanks again for the Python version update

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in figuring out that it's O(n^2) which is causing the time limit exceeded error.

Instead of using two for loops to check occurrences for each character, can you think of a way to do it in one simple pass through the string and store it?

That would significantly reduce the execution time.

You are correct in terms of space complexity.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is to use a dict to count the number of occurrences of each letter. this way you will only iterate once through your string.

sample example:

```
my_counter = {}
for letter in s:
    my_counter[letter] = my_counter.get(letter, 0) + 1
```

Because you don't want the complete solution I let you figure the rest. Hope it helps.

doc of get() : 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=get#dict.get

Answer (score 0):

Here I give a compact solution using a little bit of knowledge of python and his standard library:

This works for python>=3.7 because before it Counter wasn't defined as ordered

```py
from collections import Counter
def function_name(s):
    count = Counter(s)
    answer = [c for c, num in count.items() if num % 2]
    return answer
```

For other versions a little change taking characters in order from the string:

```py
from collections import Counter
def function_name(s):
    count = Counter(s)
    answer = [c for c in s if count[c] % 2]
    return answer
```